# URL forwarding using Chrome webRequest after response is received

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, webrequest

I am attempting to create a Chrome extension that utilizes Chrome's [webRequest](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html) module to perform a redirect to a URL obtained from an initially accessed URL. For this I would like to utilize only Chrome's webRequest functions (e.g., onBeforeSendHeaders, onHeadersReceived) and not simply perform a call to $.ajax() with the obtained URL. The desired functionality is:

1. User enters a URL in the address bar
2. A request is made and the secondary URL is extracted from the HTTP response
3. The [chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html#event-onHeadersReceived) handler redirects the user to this secondary URL using the redirectUrl attribute of a blocking response.

My attempt at accomplishing this is:

```
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(
 function(details){
  var secondaryURL = extractSecondaryURL(details);
  return {redirectUrl: secondaryURL}; //this doesn't work
 },
 {urls:["http://*/*", "https://*/*"]},
 ["blocking","responseHeaders"]
);
```

...but the page is never forwarded. The webRequest documentation says, "Only used as a response to the onBeforeRequest event." about the *redirectUrl* attribute, which is the likely culprit.

How does one perform this sort of forwarding using data received from the response headers and the Chrome webRequest module?

Comment: `redirectUrl` in `onHeadersReceived` has been requested at https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=280464. Please star the issue!

Answer (score 7):

[**web request API**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html) Methods

- [**onBeforeRequest**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html#event-onBeforeRequest) allows cancelling or redirecting a request
- [**onBeforeSendHeaders**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html#event-onBeforeSendHeaders), [**onHeadersReceived**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html#event-onHeadersReceived) allows cancelling a request or modifying headers
- [**onAuthRequired**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html#event-onAuthRequired) allows providing\modifying authentication credentials.

So, idea is to store the secondary URL from onHeadersReceived Event and fire a  [`chrome.tabs.reload()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-reload) event which fires onBeforeRequest event again which helps in redirecting.

## Sample Demonstration

The following untested :) demonstration blocks all [`Facebook`](https://www.facebook.com/) URL's and redirects them to [`Google`](http://www.google.co.in/) upon receiving secondary URL, you can customize it further.

### References

- [**Web request**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html)
- [**Background Page**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html)
- **[Manifest File](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html)**

#### `manifest.json`

Ensure all permissions are available and register background page with extension.

```
{
  "name": "Hanlder for Navigation",
  "description": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16928912/url-forwarding-using-chrome-webrequest-after-response-is-received",
  "version": "1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "permissions":["https://www.facebook.com/*","webRequest","webRequestBlocking","tabs"]
}
```

#### `background.js`

This code blocks all URL request to [`Facebook`](https://www.facebook.com/) and redirects them to [`Google`](https://www.facebook.com/).

```
var _redirectURL = "";
// Register an event listener which 
//traces all requests before being fired
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function (details) {
    if (_redirectURL != "") {
        return {
            redirectUrl: "http://www.google.co.in/" /*Redirection URL*/
        };
    }
}, {
    urls: ["*://www.facebook.com/*"] /* List of URL's */ * *
}, ["blocking"]); // Block intercepted requests until this handler has finished
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(function (details) {
    if (_redirectURL == "") {
        var secondaryURL = extractSecondaryURL(details);
        _redirectUrl = secondaryURL;
        chrome.tabs.reload();
    }
}, {
    urls: ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
}, ["blocking", "responseHeaders"]);
```

### `Output`

All request(s) to [`Facebook`](https://www.facebook.com/) are redirected to [`Google`](https://www.google.co.in/).

Comment: This method is slightly flawed, because it reloads the whole tab for all requests (including requests within **frames** and images / stylesheets / scripts / ...).

Comment: Yup, this can be slightly improved by setting the tabID passed from  callback on tabs.reload() method.

Comment: I just tried this example but I can't get it to redirect. I see no errors in the console. Is there anything I could be missing?

Comment: Curious, couldn't you 
        `return {
            redirectUrl: "http://www.google.co.in/" /*Redirection URL*/
        };` from the onHeadersReceived rather than forcing the tab.reload?

Comment: I used @GregDomjan approach and it works fine. no need to reload and add another listener for the `onBeforeRequest` event.