# Tracking URL for chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension for which i need to track if the URL requested by the user matches a URL from a default list. If it does, then I must redirect to a different page.

In my current implementation, I use a timer to periodically check the url of the page with the elements in the list. But this makes it slow and unclean because the page has to load first. I know that security reasons prevent the capture of outgoing http requests. Instead, is there anyway, I can read the url of the incoming page ?

Also, instead of using a timer to check periodically, can I detect the event of the request being made ?

Thank you.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`chrome.webRequest` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest)

> `onBeforeRequest` (optionally synchronous) - Fires when a request is about
>   to occur. This event is sent before any TCP connection is made and can
>   be used to cancel or redirect requests.

You will need to utilize the `onBeforeRequest` event to listen to requests. This will also eliminate the need for periodic checking as per your existing implementation.

Also, here's a similar [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16928912/url-forwarding-using-chrome-webrequest-after-response-is-received) which you can use as an example.