# tracking URL with set interval

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, setinterval, window.location

First post, so hello all!
I am creating a chrome extension for a research study and need to track users browser interactions, basically tracking the web pages they visit as they carry out an information seeking task.

I have read many examples on SO and various documentation (mozilla developers, w3schools) about tracking URL's  such as with hash changes, popstate changes etc and found

`setInterval(function(){ console.log("Currently URL is " + window.location.href); }, 1000);`

to be quite straightforward and to do exactly what I need albeit with a bit of overkill. It runs but it appears to stop tracking if I navigate beyond the first page, which is the whole point. I know that the interval ceases if the window is closed but surely this is not the case? I've also tried `document.URL` with no joy.

**Response to comments**

To clarify, what I am trying to do is observe the web sites that people interact with, when shuttling between google search page and the various web sites they view. The reason I use interval was because it is not just tab switching, although this is one interaction I need to watch for. I figured rather than having multiple event listeners for hyperlinks, tabs etc, if I check for changes in the URL every second or half-second then it would identify when users are exploring websites or not. I guess, if users are using multiple tabs/windows then the interval wouldn't work? But in my test case I wasn't, so I don't know why the interval would stop. I hope that helps clarify.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you explain a bit more what you are willing to achieve?

Comment: Why would you be using interval for this? There are events that you can detect the tabs changing.

Comment: You may want to check [chrome-track-activity source code](https://github.com/aakashns/chrome-track-activity). It should be useful.

Comment: maybe related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35779672/tracking-url-for-chrome-extension and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16928912/url-forwarding-using-chrome-webrequest-after-response-is-received

Comment: @aloisdg the chrome-track-activity code may just be the thing, when I can i'll implement and if so sign off, but for my own curiosity, I'd like to know why interval would cease to work in my test case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from a friend outside SO:

> The reason it doesn't track beyond the first page is because the manifest specifies that contentScript should be loaded on every Google search result page. Therefore if the user navigates away from a Google result page the extension doesn't load the script and the extension doesn't do anything.  You could move the interval location tracking to a separate background script?